# Parametric Imaginary Plots on Mathematica

Tags: plot, wolfram-mathematica

I am trying to plot the trajectory of  [image] . I tried this on Mathematica but I don't get the desired cone-like shape:

```
ParametricPlot[{I*Sin[u]*Sin[t], -I, 1}, {u, 0, Pi}, {t, 0, 10000}]
```

The result is just a blank plot with the axes. I am not sure how to make the plot both imaginary and parametric.

Comment: It's hard do plot in C^3... You have to decide what to show. Use probably ParametricPlot3D. And leave Imaginary units for labeling since plotting happens if you provide real numbers.

Comment: how does a complex valued 3-vector in two parameters result in a real surface? ( or a volume? ).  This is more of a math question than a programming one I think.

Comment: I agree with @Kuba that this looks like `ParametricPlot3D`, especially as yo vary `u` and `t`. The upper limit of `t` being `10000`? I guess `2PI` would do it. As in the present definition `x` and `y` are always imaginary, just remove the `I` and consider the printed axes as imaginary axis. *Mathematica* does not plot imaginary values, only `Re[]` and `Im[]`